# Speeding up years of Windows patch backlog

Tags: windows, patch-management

In a 200 Windows server estate there are years of missing patches. What is the quickest way to patch those? Is WSUS smart enough to batch-install maximum patches to minimise reboots? Servers are mostly "generic" so there is somewhat less of a concern about patching breaking things.

Comment: When available, you should get _cumulative_ updates. But it's still going to be quite a large amount of updates.

Comment: Is there an intelligent way of selecting those?

Comment: it's windows updates, it will never be fast. i'd start installing updates on friday night and hope by monday it's finished. I pray every time our server 03 reboots and applies updates, scary stuff

Comment: I'd go the WSUS route... This way you can monitor it as well. And then of course start doing it regularly... (and by that I do not mean "yearly"... :)